# Binding UDP sockets where port<1024?

Tags: iphone, ios, network-programming

I think I already know the answer, but just to make sure. I am trying to listen for UDP broadcasts on a port below 1024 under iOS, and bind() returns permission denied.

On OS X I can get it to work if I run as root. Is there a way around this problem On iOS devices (without jailbreak)?

Comment: I am working with a proprietary protocol that sends UDP broadcasts on a port below 1024. Changing that is going to be difficult.

Comment: Could you talk to a computer on the same network that you put a relay software on?

Comment: @thejh That would be a serious compromise for our customer. I think the solution will be to rework the backend to use a higher-numbered port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You can't.

#### Long answer:

On most UNIX systems you need root privileges to listen on ports below 1024. Since you can not obtain root privileges on iOS using the normal SDK and APIs this is simply impossible to do.
The only way to do this would be to jailbreak the device.

Answer (score 0):

I partly agree with badcat's answer. But it is not all the truth and kind of confusing. On MAC OSX, you need root privileges to use port below 1024 while it is fine for using it on IOS.

I did run an app on my ipad and iphone using port below 1024. It works fine without jailbreak.

You can see complains from Android community "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4039". So I think  Apple did something smart!